# Is the Radeon HD 7790 supported in Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I have an MSI Radeon HD 7790 graphics card and I cannot figure out whether it's supported in Ubuntu or not, and to what extent (2D, 3D accel., VDPAU, etc).

I tried asking on a few forums but got mixed/ambiguous replies.

Does anyone here know? Where and how can I check?